# Set nginx listen ip as variables

Tags: nginx

I have tens of sites listening on multiple ip addresses at nginx.
For example,

```
server {listen 172.16.33.1:80; server_name a.com}
..
server {listen 172.16.33.1:80; server_name f.com}
server {listen 172.16.33.2:80; server_name d.com}
..
server {listen 172.16.33.2:80; server_name r.com}
server {listen 172.16.33.1:443; server_name aa.com}
server {listen 172.16.33.2:443; server_name bb.com}
server {listen 172.16.33.3:443; server_name cc.com}
```

Is there any possible way to set listen ips to variables? Like 
"$ip1=172.16.33.1; $ip2=172.16.33.2;" and then change conf to

```
server {listen $ip1:443; server_name aa.com}
server {listen $ip2:443; server_name bb.com}
```

I know about search and replace in every text editor, but it would be more easy when you change listen ip once to make effect on all corresponding sites.

Answer (score 1):

Nginx by default don't support variables for the [listen](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) directive.

But another approach to dynamically configure Nginx is by using [ansible](https://www.nginx.com/blog/official-ansible-galaxy-nginx-roles-out-now/)

Here you can check the roles: https://galaxy.ansible.com/nginxinc/

And here you can read more about ansible: https://www.ansible.com/

Comment: "Learn this enormously huge and complicated software with prohibitive learning curve to solve your problem that can be stated in one sentence".