# docker-compose.yml build fails with nginx configuration

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, devops

I'm trying to build a multi-container environment, with a client,server,worker & nginx directories and I'm getting this error:

```
nginx_1     | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version
nginx_1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
nginx_1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
nginx_1     | 2021/01/01 19:48:26 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "client:3000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:2
nginx_1     | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "client:3000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:2
```

> Why it can't find my react service running on `3000` in my latest
> check the default port has not been changed

### Architecture

- Client: React project listens on default port `3000`
- Server: The `API` server listens on port `5000`
- Worker: functions in a `js` file
- Nginx: contains the `default.conf` and `Dockerfile.dev` (Dockerfile.dev is not omitted in the previous directories)
- Some more backend services

### Nginx

This is my configuration where i try to forward requests from `/` to **client** and from `/api` to the **server**

### default.conf

```
upstream client {
    server client:3000;
}

upstream api {
    server api:5000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://client;
    }

    locatoin /api {
        rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://api;
    }
}
```

### docker-composer.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - '8081:80'
```

### Dockerfile.dev

```
FROM nginx
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Comment: How are those other containers (client & api) launched? Are those three in the same docker network?

Comment: yes they are I can update the post with the full `docker-compose.yml` if neeeded

Comment: they are lunched by `CMD ["npm","run","dev"]`  where `"dev": "nodemon"` from scripts

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you check this:

[How to connect API with React App through docker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63207679/3957754)

A quickly answer to your question:

> Why it can't find my react service running on 3000 in my latest check the default port has not been changed

Your nginx configuration is not able to determine the real ip. Instead of this, is using **client or api** strings:

```
host not found in upstream client:3000 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:2
```

#### Quickly and not recommend solution

If you are using docker-compose, all of your apps will run in the same host, so the ip is the same for all of them.

You need to **hardcode** the ip of this host in your **default.conf**

```
upstream client {
    server 10.10.10.50:3000;
}

upstream api {
    server 10.10.10.50:5000;
}
```

#### Dynamic nginx

According to these links, **Nginx by default don't support variables**

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47548062/3957754
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/15432888/3957754
- https://serverfault.com/a/644898/490115

In order to avoid the hardcoded ip in **default.conf** you need to use some tool like [ansible](https://galaxy.ansible.com/nginxinc/) or create some script to replace a placeholder in your **default.conf**

```
upstream client {
    server #IP:3000;
}

upstream api {
    server #IP:5000;
}
```

bash script:

```
sed -i "s/#IP/$MY_IP/g" /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

docker-composer.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - '8081:80'
    environment:
      MY_IP: ${MY_IP}
```

Here you need to create a custom nginx Dockerfile which is able to execute the script to replace the ip or use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47615751/docker-compose-run-a-script-after-container-has-started)

Finally just run:

```
export MY_IP=10.10.10.50
docker-compose up -d ...
```

#### docker-compose = development

Docker compose in my opinion is jut for development, stagging or testing phase, not for production

In production each app must be in a isolated host:

- nginx
- api
- web

In this case, each app must have a different ip, so your nginx must be able to handled them.

In prod you could use another tools to create dynamic nginx configuration files

- ansible

Or more advanced loadbalancers

- AWS Elastic Load Balancing.
- Traefik
- LiteSpeed
- etc

Comment: Thank you for the post, the truth is i'd like to avoid hardcoded IP's. I'm planning to deploy it to AWS Elastic Beanstack in production mode through Travis. I'll look into the script although I already have a `Dockerfle.dev` for `Nginx`